# Java ternary operator is automatically wide casting an int to double during string concatenation

Tags: java, string, int, double, conditional-operator

I am trying to create a set of file paths using some numeric values from an array and read those files. The folders have the exact numeric values in their name except for when the value is 1.0. So if the value is 1.2 the folder is like

> data/text/1.2/

When the value is 1.0 the folder is

> data/text/1/

So I was trying to use the ternary operator and got an unexpected result. Here is the code -

```
double key = 1.0;
String path = "data/text/" + (key == 1.0 ? 1 : key) + "/";
System.out.println(path);
        
String path2 = "data/text/" + 1 + "/";
System.out.println(path2);
```

The output is as follows:

> data/text/1.0/
>
> data/text/1/

Shouldn't the value in the first case also be?

> data/text/1/

I expected that value since I am using the integer literal.

Is this some kind of bug that in case of ternary operator the int value gets casted to double? Or am I getting somthing wrong?

Comment: Every expression in Java has a compile-time type, including ternary expressions. "`int` or `double`" is not a possible type, so in order for this ternary expression to have a type, either one or both operands has to be converted to a different type.

Comment: If you change it to `(key == 1.0 ? "1" : key)` you tell the compiler that the result should be a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick a definite return type for your ternary operation. It has to both be something to which the 2nd and 3rd operands can be converted, and appropriate for how the ternary result will be used.

As a simple strategy, look at how you plan to use the result, and pick the type for that use. Force one or both operands to that type.

In the case in the question, the result is going to be concatenated with a String. Using `"1"` instead of `1` forces the ternary result type to String. `key` can be converted to String, so you only need to change one operand.